# How to create a new row for each comma separated value in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
text                   category 
sfsd sgvv              abc,xyz
zydf sefs sdfsd        yyy
dfsd dsrgd dggr        xyz
eter vxg wfe           abc
dfvf ertet             abc,xyz
```

I want an output like this:

```
text                   category 
sfsd sgvv              abc
sfsd sgvv              xyz
zydf sefs sdfsd        yyy
dfsd dsrgd dggr        xyz
eter vxg wfe           abc
dfvf ertet             abc
dfvf ertet             abc
```

Basically create a new row for each two or more category in `category` column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (pandas 0.25+) with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df1 = (df.assign(category = df['category'].str.split(','))
         .explode('category')
         .reset_index(drop=True))
```

For oldier pandas versions first [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for not separator column(s), then [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), last [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) - first for remove second level of `MultiIndex` and then for convert index to column:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('text')['category']
         .str.split(',', expand=True)
         .stack()
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index(name='category'))
print (df1)
              text category
0        sfsd sgvv      abc
1        sfsd sgvv      xyz
2  zydf sefs sdfsd      yyy
3  dfsd dsrgd dggr      xyz
4     eter vxg wfe      abc
5       dfvf ertet      abc
6       dfvf ertet      xyz
```

Comment: Sorry, something seems to be wrong. It is creating way more rows than expected. In my original DF, i have multiple columns not just "text"

Answer (score 2):

Try using `set_index` + `stack` + `str.split` + `unstack` + `reset_index` for much older versions:

```
print(df.set_index('text')
      .stack()
      .str.split(', ', expand=True)
      .stack()
      .unstack(-2)
      .reset_index(-1, drop=True)
      .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 1):

Linking to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622470/fast-way-to-split-column-into-multiple-rows-in-pandas), try the following code for your dataframe:

> We can first split the column, expand it, stack it and then join it back to the original df like below:

```
df.drop('category', axis=1).join(
  df['category'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True).rename('category'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Below will give the output you need. Assuming df is your dataset name.

```
new_df_skel = dict()
new_df_skel['text'] = list()
new_df_skel['category'] = list()

for index,item in df.iterrows():
  item = dict(item)
  unref_cat = item['category']
  if "," in unref_cat:
    for strip in unref_cat.split(','):
      new_df_skel['category'].append(strip)
      new_df_skel['text'].append(item['text'])
  else:
    new_df_skel['category'].append(strip)
    new_df_skel['text'].append(unref_cat)

new_dataset = pd.DataFrame(new_df_skel)
```

Have a great day!