# Python Create new row for each value within lists in two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare the values of a list within two columns so I would like to create a separate row for each list index in that column where the row name contains the index of the list. My dataframe looks like:

```
   File    Color         File Value              True Value
    1       blue    ['123', 'abc', 'tvr']    ['123', 'abc', 'tvr']
    2       green   ['jlak', 'abc', 'vds']   ['123', 'ffs', 'tvr']
    3       red     ['vssf', 'blue', '15a']  ['15a', 'asd', '15a', '234']
    4       black      'fvg'                     'fvg'
```

I want the data frame to look like:

```
   File     Color         File Value              True Value
    1       blue_0          '123'                    '123'
    1       blue_1          'abc'                    'abc'
    1       blue_2          'tvr'                    'tvr'
    2       green_0         'jlak'                   '123'
    2       green_1         'abc'                    'ffs'
    2       green_2         'vds'                    'tvr'
    3       red_0           'vssf'                   '15a'
    3       red_1           'blue'                   'asd'
    3       red_2           '15a'                    '15a'
    3       red_3            None                    '234'
    4       black           'fvg'                    'fvg'
```

I have tried using the solution from here: [How to create a new row for each comma separated value in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59640789/how-to-create-a-new-row-for-each-comma-separated-value-in-a-column-in-pandas) but I keep getting nulls and don't know how to apply it when I have some rows that aren't lists.

```
(data.assign(category = data['File Value'].explode('File Value').reset_index(drop=True)))
```

I have tried subsetting the dataframe to get only the rows that have lists:

```
sub = data[~data.Color == 'black']
(sub.assign(category = sub['File Value'].explode('File Value').reset_index(drop=True)))
```

But I again get a column of all nulls

**UPDATE:**

I am using explode to separate the column values into separate rows, but don't know how to modify the 'File' and 'Color' column to keep track of values

```
sub = data[~data.Color == 'black']
sub['File Value'].explode()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "isn't giving me what I need"?

Comment: how did you come to have this dataframe (presumably, you don't even say) to begin with?

Comment: This is the way the data was provided to me.

Comment: what does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) lists (*if any*) inside both columns, then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)/[`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) :

```
from itertools import zip_longest

cols = ["File Value", "True Value"] # add more if needed

expl = (
    df[cols]
        .map(lambda v: v if isinstance(v, list) else [v]) # >=2.1.0
        .apply(lambda x: list(zip(*zip_longest(*x))),
               axis=1, result_type="expand")
        .explode(list(range(len(cols))))
        .set_axis(cols, axis=1)
)

out = (
    df.drop(columns=cols).join(expl)
        .assign(Color= lambda x: x["Color"].str.cat(
            x.groupby(level=0).cumcount().astype(str), sep="_")
                .where(x.index.duplicated(keep=False), x["Color"]))
)
```

Output :

```
   File    Color File Value True Value
0     1   blue_0        123        123
0     1   blue_1        abc        abc
0     1   blue_2        tvr        tvr
1     2  green_0       jlak        123
1     2  green_1        abc        ffs
1     2  green_2        vds        tvr
2     3    red_0       vssf        15a
2     3    red_1       blue        asd
2     3    red_2        15a        15a
2     3    red_3       None        234
3     4    black        fvg        fvg

[11 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

So, there might be a more clever way to do this with a join/explode, but I think I would just normalize your data in two passes, then use `.explode`:

```
In [107]: df = pd.DataFrame(
     ...:     dict(
     ...:         file=[1, 2, 3, 4],
     ...:         color=["blue", "green", "red", "black"],
     ...:         file_value=[
     ...:             ["123", "abc", "tvr"],
     ...:             ["jlak", "abc", "vds"],
     ...:             ["vssf", "blue", "15a"],
     ...:             "fvg",
     ...:         ],
     ...:         true_value=[
     ...:             ["123", "abc", "tvr"],
     ...:             ["123", "ffs", "tvr"],
     ...:             ["15a", "asd", "15a", "234"],
     ...:             "fvg",
     ...:         ],
     ...:     )
     ...: )
```

So, define these functions to normalize the lists to the same length (and make sure they are always lists first)

```
In [108]: def normalize_to_list(x):
     ...:     if not isinstance(x, list):
     ...:         x = [x]
     ...:     return x
     ...:

In [109]: def normalize_list_lengths(S):
     ...:     # this could all probably be more elegant
     ...:     file_value = S['file_value']
     ...:     true_value = S['true_value']
     ...:     if len(file_value) == len(true_value):
     ...:         return S
     ...:     elif len(file_value) > len(true_value):
     ...:         diff = len(file_value) - len(true_value)
     ...:         true_value += [None]*diff
     ...:     else:
     ...:         diff = len(true_value) - len(file_value)
     ...:         file_value += [None]*diff
     ...:     return S
     ...:

In [110]: df
Out[110]:
   file  color         file_value            true_value
0     1   blue    [123, abc, tvr]       [123, abc, tvr]
1     2  green   [jlak, abc, vds]       [123, ffs, tvr]
2     3    red  [vssf, blue, 15a]  [15a, asd, 15a, 234]
3     4  black                fvg                   fvg

In [111]: df[['file_value', 'true_value']] = df[['file_value','true_value']].applymap(normalize_to_list)

In [112]: df
Out[112]:
   file  color         file_value            true_value
0     1   blue    [123, abc, tvr]       [123, abc, tvr]
1     2  green   [jlak, abc, vds]       [123, ffs, tvr]
2     3    red  [vssf, blue, 15a]  [15a, asd, 15a, 234]
3     4  black              [fvg]                 [fvg]

In [113]: df[['file_value', 'true_value']] = df[['file_value','true_value']].apply(normalize_list_lengths, axis=1)

In [114]: df
Out[114]:
   file  color               file_value            true_value
0     1   blue          [123, abc, tvr]       [123, abc, tvr]
1     2  green         [jlak, abc, vds]       [123, ffs, tvr]
2     3    red  [vssf, blue, 15a, None]  [15a, asd, 15a, 234]
3     4  black                    [fvg]                 [fvg]
```

Finally, use `df.explode` with the two columns:

```
In [115]: df.explode(column=['file_value','true_value'])
Out[115]:
   file  color file_value true_value
0     1   blue        123        123
0     1   blue        abc        abc
0     1   blue        tvr        tvr
1     2  green       jlak        123
1     2  green        abc        ffs
1     2  green        vds        tvr
2     3    red       vssf        15a
2     3    red       blue        asd
2     3    red        15a        15a
2     3    red       None        234
3     4  black        fvg        fvg
```